# How can I decrease timing to find measure of edges of a tetrahedron?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, timing

Let be $ABCD$ is a tetrahedron, knowing that $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle $AB=a$, $AD=d$, $BD=e$, $CD=f$. I want to find the $a$, $d$, $e$, $f$ when the angle of two vectors $AB$ and $CD$ equal to $120^\circ$ or  $60^\circ$. I know that, when the angle of two vectors $AB$ and $CD$ equal to $120^\circ$, we have $d^2 - e^2 + a f = 0$ and if the angle of two vectors $AB$ and $CD$ equal to $60^\circ$, then $d^2 - e^2 - a f = 0$. I tried with angle of two vectors $AB$ and $CD$ equal to $120^\circ$

```
    {a, d, e, f} /. 
 Solve[{d^2 - e^2 + a f == 0, 2 <= a <= 10, 2 <= d <= 10, 
   2 <= e <= 10, 2 <= f <= 10, GCD[a, d, e] == 1, 
   Abs[d - e] < a < d + e, Abs[a - e] < d < a + e, 
   Abs[d - a] < e < d + a, Abs[d - f] < a < d + f, 
   Abs[a - f] < d < a + f, Abs[d - a] < f < d + a, 
   Abs[e - f] < a < e + f, Abs[a - f] < e < a + f, 
   Abs[a - e] < a < a + e}, {a, d, e, f}, Integers]
```

> {{3, 2, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 3}, {4, 3, 5, 4}, {4, 5, 7, 6}, {5, 4, 6, 
>     4}, {5, 6, 9, 9}, {6, 5, 7, 4}, {7, 5, 9, 8}, {7, 6, 8, 4}, {8, 3, 
>     9, 9}, {8, 5, 9, 7}, {8, 7, 9, 4}, {9, 8, 10, 4}}

If I change $2 <= a <= 30, 2 <= d <= 30, 2 <= e <= 30, 2 <= f <= 30$, then the time is too long.

With Maple, the time is faster when I tried $a,d,e,f \in [2,30]$.
[image]

How can I decrease timing to find measure of edges of a tetrahedron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to only include the range restrictions, and then filter out the solutions that don't meet your other requirements. For example:

```
sol = {a, d, e, f} /. Solve[
    d^2-e^2+a f==0 && 2<=a<=30 && 2<=d<=30 && 2<=e<=30 && 2<=f<=30,
    Integers
]; //AbsoluteTiming
sol[[;;10]]
```

> {2.8215, Null}
>
> {{2, 2, 4, 6}, {2, 2, 6, 16}, {2, 2, 8, 30}, {2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 7, 20}, {2, 4, 6, 10}, {2, 4, 8, 24}, {2, 5, 7, 12}, {2, 5, 9, 28}, {2, 6, 8, 14}}

Here is a predicate that applies the rest of your requirements:

```
validQ[{a_, d_, e_, f_}] := And[
    GCD[a,d,e]==1, Abs[d-e]<a<d+e, Abs[a-e]<d<a+e, Abs[d-a]<e<d+a,
    Abs[d-f]<a<d+f, Abs[a-f]<d<a+f, Abs[d-a]<f<d+a, Abs[e-f]<a<e+f,
    Abs[a-f]<e<a+f, Abs[a-e]<a<a+e
]
```

So, the final result is:

```
Select[validQ] @ sol
```

> {{3, 2, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 3}, {4, 3, 5, 4}, {4, 5, 7, 6}, {5, 4, 6, 4}, {5, 6, 
>     9, 9}, {6, 5, 7, 4}, {6, 7, 11, 12}, {7, 5, 9, 8}, {7, 6, 8, 4}, {7, 9, 12, 
>     9}, {8, 3, 9, 9}, {8, 5, 9, 7}, {8, 5, 11, 12}, {8, 7, 9, 4}, {8, 7, 11, 
>     9}, {8, 9, 11, 5}, {8, 9, 13, 11}, {8, 11, 13, 6}, {8, 11, 15, 13}, {9, 7, 
>     11, 8}, {9, 8, 10, 4}, {9, 11, 16, 15}, {10, 7, 13, 12}, {10, 9, 11, 
>     4}, {10, 13, 17, 12}, {11, 7, 15, 16}, {11, 8, 14, 12}, {11, 9, 13, 8}, {11,
>      10, 12, 4}, {11, 13, 20, 21}, {11, 14, 19, 15}, {11, 15, 18, 9}, {12, 5, 
>     11, 8}, {12, 5, 13, 12}, {12, 7, 11, 6}, {12, 7, 13, 10}, {12, 11, 13, 
>     4}, {12, 11, 17, 14}, {12, 11, 19, 20}, {12, 13, 17, 10}, {12, 13, 19, 
>     16}, {12, 17, 23, 20}, {12, 19, 23, 14}, {13, 8, 18, 20}, {13, 9, 17, 
>     16}, {13, 10, 16, 12}, {13, 11, 15, 8}, {13, 12, 14, 4}, {13, 15, 24, 
>     27}, {13, 16, 23, 21}, {13, 17, 22, 15}, {13, 18, 21, 9}, {14, 9, 19, 
>     20}, {14, 11, 17, 12}, {14, 13, 15, 4}, {14, 17, 25, 24}, {14, 19, 23, 
>     12}, {15, 4, 14, 12}, {15, 4, 16, 16}, {15, 7, 17, 16}, {15, 8, 17, 
>     15}, {15, 11, 14, 5}, {15, 11, 16, 9}, {15, 11, 19, 16}, {15, 13, 17, 
>     8}, {15, 13, 22, 21}, {15, 13, 23, 24}, {15, 14, 16, 4}, {15, 14, 19, 
>     11}, {15, 16, 19, 7}, {15, 16, 26, 28}, {15, 17, 22, 13}, {15, 17, 23, 
>     16}, {15, 19, 26, 21}, {15, 22, 28, 20}, {15, 23, 28, 17}, {16, 7, 15, 
>     11}, {16, 7, 17, 15}, {16, 9, 15, 9}, {16, 9, 17, 13}, {16, 11, 19, 
>     15}, {16, 11, 21, 20}, {16, 13, 19, 12}, {16, 13, 21, 17}, {16, 15, 17, 
>     4}, {16, 15, 23, 19}, {16, 15, 25, 25}, {16, 17, 23, 15}, {16, 17, 25, 
>     21}, {16, 19, 27, 23}, {16, 19, 29, 30}, {16, 21, 27, 18}, {16, 21, 29, 
>     25}, {17, 11, 23, 24}, {17, 12, 22, 20}, {17, 13, 21, 16}, {17, 14, 20, 
>     12}, {17, 15, 19, 8}, {17, 16, 18, 4}, {17, 21, 30, 27}, {17, 22, 29, 
>     21}, {17, 23, 28, 15}, {18, 11, 25, 28}, {18, 13, 23, 20}, {18, 17, 19, 
>     4}, {18, 25, 29, 12}, {19, 12, 26, 28}, {19, 13, 25, 24}, {19, 14, 24, 
>     20}, {19, 15, 23, 16}, {19, 16, 22, 12}, {19, 17, 21, 8}, {19, 18, 20, 
>     4}, {20, 7, 23, 24}, {20, 9, 19, 14}, {20, 9, 21, 18}, {20, 11, 19, 
>     12}, {20, 11, 21, 16}, {20, 13, 23, 18}, {20, 13, 27, 28}, {20, 17, 23, 
>     12}, {20, 17, 27, 22}, {20, 19, 21, 4}, {20, 19, 29, 24}, {20, 21, 29, 
>     20}, {20, 23, 27, 10}, {21, 5, 23, 24}, {21, 8, 20, 16}, {21, 8, 22, 
>     20}, {21, 10, 25, 25}, {21, 11, 25, 24}, {21, 13, 20, 11}, {21, 13, 22, 
>     15}, {21, 16, 23, 13}, {21, 16, 26, 20}, {21, 17, 25, 16}, {21, 19, 23, 
>     8}, {21, 19, 26, 15}, {21, 20, 22, 4}, {21, 20, 29, 21}, {21, 22, 29, 
>     17}, {21, 23, 26, 7}, {22, 15, 29, 28}, {22, 17, 27, 20}, {22, 19, 25, 
>     12}, {22, 21, 23, 4}, {23, 16, 30, 28}, {23, 17, 29, 24}, {23, 18, 28, 
>     20}, {23, 19, 27, 16}, {23, 20, 26, 12}, {23, 21, 25, 8}, {23, 22, 24, 
>     4}, {24, 5, 23, 21}, {24, 5, 25, 25}, {24, 7, 23, 20}, {24, 7, 25, 24}, {24,
>      11, 23, 17}, {24, 11, 25, 21}, {24, 11, 29, 30}, {24, 13, 23, 15}, {24, 13,
>      25, 19}, {24, 13, 29, 28}, {24, 17, 23, 10}, {24, 17, 25, 14}, {24, 17, 29,
>      23}, {24, 19, 23, 7}, {24, 19, 25, 11}, {24, 19, 29, 20}, {24, 23, 25, 
>     4}, {24, 23, 29, 13}, {24, 25, 29, 9}, {25, 21, 29, 16}, {25, 22, 28, 
>     12}, {25, 23, 27, 8}, {25, 24, 26, 4}, {26, 23, 29, 12}, {26, 25, 27, 
>     4}, {27, 25, 29, 8}, {27, 26, 28, 4}, {28, 11, 25, 18}, {28, 13, 27, 
>     20}, {28, 13, 29, 24}, {28, 15, 27, 18}, {28, 15, 29, 22}, {28, 17, 25, 
>     12}, {28, 27, 29, 4}, {29, 28, 30, 4}, {30, 11, 29, 24}, {30, 19, 29, 16}}